# DNN (DotNetNuke) module exceptions not logging

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I have a customer's DNN site with a custom module that's having issues with module error logging. The site was upgraded to version 7.4 from 6.2 and now to version 9.0. Module exceptions no longer appear in Admin / Host Events since the upgrade to 7.4. It appears module exception logging was changed in DNN 7.4 [as explained here](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/155166/improved-event-logging-in-dnn-74). This is the code that worked before but now nothing gets logged;

Test object:

```
public class foo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string bar { get; set; }
}
```

Test webapi Controller:

```
[DnnAuthorize]
public class MyCustomModuleController : DnnApiController
{
    private static readonly ILog Logger = LoggerSource.Instance.GetLogger(typeof(MyCustomModuleController));


    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFoo(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            foo test = null;
            var bar = test.bar; //will throw null exception

            ...

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex); //no log entries in db since ver. 7.4
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Server error");
        }
    }
```

Is there a setting that I should enable or is there a new way of logging events?

Comment: Did the upgrade change anything in your DotNetNuke.log4net.config?

Comment: @DotNetNuclear, log4Net config file hasn't changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that DotNetNuke.Instrumentation.GetLogger() returns the logging object for doing the Log4Net logging to file appender logs stored in: /Portals/_default/Logs. You can also view them from Host > Host Settings > Logs.

Normally, you would add to your class by setting it up in a constructor and calling the .Error()/.ErrorFormat(), .Warn()/.WarnFormat(), etc functions to append an error or information message to the logging file.

```
public class MyCustomModuleController : DnnApiController
{
    private DotNetNuke.Instrumentation.ILog Logger { get; set; }

    public MyCustomModuleController()
    {
        Logger = DotNetNuke.Instrumentation.LoggerSource.Instance.GetLogger(this.GetType());
    }

    public HttpResponseMessage GetFoo(int id)
    {
        try
        {
           ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error(ex); 
        }
    }
}
```

The other logging technique available is using the DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions to log the exception to the database.  These errors get added to the EventLog and Exceptions tables.

```
public class MyCustomModuleController : DnnApiController
{   
    public HttpResponseMessage GetFoo(int id)
    {
        try
        {
           ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.LogException(ex); 
        }
    }
}
```

It is possible that DNN disconnected the Log4Net process with the EventLog.  I can't remember how it worked back in version 6.

Comment: I tested `DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions.LogException(ex)` and it works. It appears they made a breaking change with the Log4Net implementation as the method isn't deprecated. I'll mark your answer as accepted but I'll file a ticket in the issue tracker. Thanks